# Does a GUI exist to play on www.lichess.org with a Windows Computer?

Tags: software

I noticed that if you play with a GUI the chess board looks way better. For example, I use ChessBase Reader to play in playchess.com

I would like to know if there is a GUI for [www.lichess.org](http://www.lichess.org)

Comment: Would changing the appearance of the board and pieces in the lichess web interface be sufficient? (By the way, the lichess web UI *is* a GUI; what you are looking for is a desktop client, it sounds like.)

Comment: Hey Brian! Thank you for all your ideas! You are right in all what you said.  Unfortunately, It seems that the chess board cannot be increased. That is why I am looking for an alternative solution. When I used ChessBase Reader the chess board is way bigger. I use my Windows laptop to play chess. That is why is important.

Comment: You can make the board bigger in lichess, from lichess board feature itself. If it is not enough, you can use zoom feature of the browser.

Comment: @Minot Thank you for the information! I used the zoom feature of the browser and it does not work well in my laptop, even though I have seen that it works well with a bigger screen like the one that the desktops have. I will check the lichess board feature that you mentioned.